# Margins of matplotlib.pyplot.imshow when used in subplot environment

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot, imshow

I am trying to plot the values of several arrays in separate plots of a figure using imshow.

When I plot one image only, and use the plt.imshow() command with the correct extents, the figure comes out perfectly.
However, when I try to create multiple plots of this image in the same figure, using plt.subplot(), each of these plots ends up with incorrect x-axis settings, and there are white margins. I tried correcting the x-axis range with the set_xlim() command, but it has no effect (which I also don't understand).

The minimal working sample is below - any help would be appreciated!

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as n

image = n.array([[ 1.,  2.,  2.,  5.],
   [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  3.],
   [ 1.,  2.,  0.,  2.],
   [ 4.,  2.,  3.,  2.]])
xextent, yextent= n.shape(image)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,sharex=True, sharey=True)
im0 = ax[0].imshow(image, extent=(0,xextent,yextent,0),interpolation='nearest');
ax[0].set_xlim([0,4])
im1 = ax[1].imshow(image, extent=(0,xextent,yextent,0),interpolation='nearest');
ax[1].set_xlim([0,4])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This seems to be triggered by setting `sharex` and `sharey` on `subplots` call. Do you need to these for your usecase?

Comment: I see, thanks. But yes, I do need those - in the end I want a four by four plot, and I want to not waste space on axes labels.

Comment: In that case you may be better off manually turning off the tick and axes labels on the subplots you don't need them for.

Comment: This works, thanks. It does seem to be `sharex` and `sharey` that create the problem when used with `imshow`. 
When I use `pcolormesh` (with subplots, and `sharex`/`sharey`), it's actually fine and I also don't get redundant whitespace (the `ax[0].set_xlim` command also works again then).

Comment: That's interesting -- I would consider filing a bug report with the Matplotlib folk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the options are:

1. Remove the `sharex`/`sharey` keywords - seems to clash with imshow in the subplot environment. (Suggested by [xnx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/293594/xnx))
2. Use `plt.subplots_adjust` with appropriate settings, in combination with `plt.gcf().tight_layout()` (Suggested by [mwormser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5528308/mwormser))
3. Use pcolormesh instead of imshow in the subplot environment.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the reason for the whitespace is the size of the window. You can either change the window size (you'd have to figure out the numbers) or you can adjust the subplot. I found this out by playing with the "configure subplots" button in the image popup.

```
plt.subplots_adjust(right=0.4)
```

With this line the plot will have no whitespace, but still some empty space (which you can fix by adjusting the window size).

Comment: Ok yes, this works. I can also use this for a four by four subplot when I play with top, bottom and left etc. It does make producing lots of these images (for a movie) somewhat difficult, especially as I want colorbars on the side which I insert with an inset - which then gets shifted around, so it involves a lot of playing. Will accept as answer if nothing more suitable to multiple image generation comes up - thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped, even if only a little. I guess if you have larger plots that extend the standard figure size the problem will vanish. It's almost always a good idea to also use `plt.gcf().tight_layout()` to automatically fix the arrangement of the plots.