# Issue about subplot imshow in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I generate two wordcloud pictures and I wanna put the two pictures in a `eps` figure. I tried successfully with `subplot`, but the two wordcloud pictures are so small and there is large margin in the figure. I was wondering what can I do to enlarge those two wordcloud pictures and don't leave the margin?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.imshow(f_senti_wc)
plt.axis("off")
plt.title('Female Wordcloud')

plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.imshow(m_senti_wc)
plt.axis("off")
plt.title('Male Wordcloud')

plt.savefig("Fig1_worcloud.eps")
```

The whole figure:
[image]

Comment: This [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38967478/margins-of-matplotlib-pyplot-imshow-when-used-in-subplot-environment) will be useful.

Comment: @Sameeresque Thank you for comment. Tried but still doesn't work. Any other ideas?